# JQuery: Appending Attribute Value to Each Element

Tags: jquery

I am trying to append an additional url chunk to an existing attribute and simply update it.

```
$("img").each(function (i) {
    var originalSrc = $("img").attr('src');
    $("img").attr('src', 'http://www.domain-name.com/' + originalSrc);    
});

$("a").each(function (i) {
    var originalHref = $("a").attr('href');
    $("a").attr('href', 'http://www.domain-name.com/' + originalHref);    
});
```

It is counting all elements and appending a long string to the final attribute.  I understand what's going on, but I'm not sure the correct way to go about this.  This is obviously wrong.

Essentially, I'm scrubbing a remote page and I need to reset all relative connections to absolute.

Comment: I'm not certain I understand, what's the wrong part of this?

Comment: I didn't drink enough coffee this morning, that's what! :-)  Thanks guys.  Such a silly thing to have a mistake over.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try:

```
$("img").each(function () {
    var originalSrc = $(this).attr('src');
    $(this).attr('src', 'http://www.domain-name.com/' + originalSrc);    
});
```

Answer (score 8):

Even less work with (compare http://api.jquery.com/attr/) :

```
$("img").attr('src', function(i, val){
   return 'http://www.domain.com/' + val;
});

$("a").attr('href', function(i, val){
   return 'http://www.domain.com/' + val;
});
```

Greets

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using the  `each` method to loop over your elements, you should use the `this` keyword inside the callback function, to refer to the currently iterated element:

```
$("img").each(function (i) {
    var image = $(this), // 'this' is the image element being iterated
        originalSrc = image.attr('src');

    image.attr('src', 'http://www.domain-name.com/' + originalSrc);    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside each function use `$(this)` instead of `$(a)` and `$(img)`.

Answer (score 0):

Using your code structure:

```
$("img").each(function (i) {
    var $img = $(this);
    var originalSrc = $img.attr('src');   // use "this" in the $() function to get the current element...
    $img.attr('src', 'http://www.domain-name.com/' + originalSrc);    
});

$("a").each(function (i) {
    var $a = $(this);
    var originalHref = $a.attr('href');
    $a.attr('href', 'http://www.domain-name.com/' + originalHref);    
});
```

Make sure to use `$(this)` inside of jQuery's callback functions to retrieve the 'current' node in the node list.